# why? ng-pattern is not working on my directive

Tags: angularjs

### angularjs code

```js
app.directive("textPan", function() {
  return {
    scope: {
      name: "@",
      label: "@",
      id: "=",
      readonly: "@",
      pattern: "@"
    },
    template: [
      ' <div class="form-group">',
      ' <label class="control-label" id="lbl{{name}}">{{label}}</label>',
      ' <input   id="txt{{name}}" class="form-control" ng-model="val" name="txt{{name}}" ng-readonly={{readonly}} ng-pattern="/^[A-Za-z]{5}\d{4}[A-Za-z]{1}$/"   required />',
      ' <span ng-show="myForm.txt{{name}}.$error.required" class="text-danger ">This field is required.</span>',
      '<span ng-show="myForm.txt{{name}}.$error.pattern" class=""><em></em>PAN CARd is not valid</span>',
      ' </div>'
    ].join("")
  };
});
```

The problem is that every everything going ok, but`ng-pattern` not working properly

Comment: have you tested your regex? do you need `$` at the end of it?

Comment: Relevant docs: [ng-pattern](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngPattern)

Comment: <input   class="form-control" ng-model="val"  ng-pattern="/^[A-Za-z]{5}\d{4}[A-Za-z]{1}$/"   required /> when i used this code it is working fine.. when i used ng-pattern inside the directive it is not working.why?

Comment: @AlekseySolovey i don't want $ at end ☺☺ . i want simple solution***